# Отключить изменение курсора, когда наводишь мышку на окно. Gtk python

Tags: python, gtk

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы был какой-то текст, который следует за мышкой

```css
import cairo, gi, pyautogui, time
gi.require_version('Gtk','3.0')
from gi.repository import Gtk,Gdk
from threading import Thread

class TransparentWindow(Gtk.Window):
 def __init__(self):
  super().__init__()
  
  self.text = Gtk.Label()
  self.text.set_text("Teeeeeeeeeeeeeees")
  self.text.set_sensitive(False)
  self.box = Gtk.Box()
  self.box.pack_start(self.text, True, True, 0)
  
  screen = self.get_screen()
  visual = screen.get_rgba_visual()
  
  if visual and screen.is_composited():
   self.set_visual(visual)
   
  self.set_keep_above(True) 
  self.set_decorated(False) 
  self.set_app_paintable(True)
  self.add(self.box)
  self.connect('draw', self.draw)
  
  self.show_all()
  
 def draw(self,widget,context):
  context.set_source_rgba(0,0,0,0)
  context.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_SOURCE)
  context.paint()
  context.set_operator(cairo.OPERATOR_OVER)
  
win = TransparentWindow()
def track():
 while 1:
  pos = pyautogui.position()
  win.move(pos.x + 20,pos.y)
  time.sleep(0.035)
thread = Thread(target = track)
thread.start()
Gtk.main()
thread.stop()
```

Способ явно не самый лучший ( Может есть более эффективный ? ). Получается есть окно, у которого нет `TitleBar`-a и у которого прозрачный фон. Когда я двигаю мышку правее, то окно в момент, когда текст "стукается" об край экрана, перестает двигаться направо, хотя я все еще могу продолжать двигать мышку направо, из-за этого мышка контактирует с окном и меняет курсор. Как сделать окно неактивным или что-то , что поможет избежать изменения курсора ?

Answer (score 0):

Окна, с которыми не может взаимодействовать мышь (прозрачные для мыши) называются OSD (on screen display). Для их создания надо при создании окна выставить определённые флаги.

В [этом ответе](//stackoverflow.com/a/4069495/4928642) даётся ссылка на [пример приложения](//www.codeproject.com/Articles/12597/OSD-window-with-animation-effect-in-C) (правда, на C#) и инструкцию, в соответствии с коророй надо указать следующие значения для [ExStyle](//docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/winmsg/extended-window-styles):

- `WS_EX_TOPMOST` чтобы окно отображалось поверх других
- `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` чтобы окно было визуально прозрачным
- `WS_EX_LAYERED` (для Windows 2000+) и `WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW` для прозрачности для мыши, клавиатуры и системы